# Can you help with a Statistics Question involving expected values of a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> The Question: Let $Y$ have probability density function, $f_y(y) = 2(1-y), 0\leq y \leq 1$. Suppose that $W= Y^2$, in which case, $f_w(w)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{w}} -1, 0 \leq w \leq 1$. Find $E(W)$ in two different ways.

The Attempt: I am a little confused on what they mean by "find $E(W)$ in two different ways." However, here is what I got so far.

To find $E(g(Y))$, $$E(g(Y)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y)f_{y}(y) dy.$$ 
Since we know that $W= Y^2$, this means that

$$E(W) = \int_{0}^{1} y^2(2-2y) dy = \left.\left(\frac{2}{3}y^3 -\frac{1}{2}y^4\right) \right|_{0}^{1}= \frac{1}{6}.$$

For the second way, since we know that $f_{w}(w) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{w}} -1$ and $W= Y^2$, this implies $f_{w}(y) = \frac{1}{y} -1$. To find this expected value, $E(W) = \int_{0}^{1} (\frac{1}{y} -1)(2-2y) dy$. This is all I got so far. I am not sure if I am on the right track. Can you give me some hints on this please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The second approach should be $\int_0^1 x (x^{-1/2}-1) dx$ (integrate $x$ against the density function you are given).

Comment: You can use `\left.` and `\right|` to get the size of the evaluation bar right: `\left.\left(\frac23y^3-\frac12y^4\right)\right|_0^1` yields $\left.\left(\frac23y^3-\frac12y^4\right)\right|_0^1$.

Comment: @joriki I went ahead and did that because the formatting was hurting my eyes :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to compute $\mathbb E[W]$ is to make use of the fact that for a nonnegative random variable $X$ with distribution function $F$,
$$\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\ \mathsf dw.  $$
First we compute the distribution function of $W$: if $0<w<1$ then
$$F_W(w) = \int_0^w \left(z^{-\frac12} - 1\right)\ \mathsf dz = 2w^{\frac12} - w, $$
so $F_W(w) = \left(2w^{\frac12}-w\right)\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(w) + \mathsf 1_{[1,\infty)}(w)$. Hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[W] &= \int_0^1 (1-F_W(w))\mathsf dw\\
&= \int_0^1 \left(1 + w - 2w^{\frac12}\right)\ \mathsf dw\\
&= \frac16.
\end{align}